# Add more than one `add_n`

Tags: gtsummary

Is it possible to add more than one `add_n`? The following code returns the following warning and neither `add_n` is added. On their own both work.

`! Column "n" not found and was ignored.`

```r
iris %>%
gtsummary::tbl_summary(type = list(where(is.logical) ~ "categorical"),
                       missing_text = 'Missing',
                       missing = 'ifany') %>%
gtsummary::add_n(statistic = "{N_nonmiss}", col_label = "**N responses**") %>%
gtsummary::add_n(statistic = "{N_miss}", col_label = "**Missing**")
```

Comment: you are missing the data argument in your function call? can you share the data so we can reproduce the error

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I added iris and more details on the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can make two table one with the response N and statistics and then one table with the missing N and use `tbl_merge()` to combine them.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
t1 <- iris %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(type = list(where(is.logical) ~ "categorical"),
                         missing_text = 'Missing',
                         missing = 'ifany') %>%
  gtsummary::add_n(statistic = "{N_nonmiss}", 
                   col_label = "**N responses**")

t2 <- iris %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(type = list(where(is.logical) ~ "categorical"),
                         missing_text = 'Missing',
                         missing = 'ifany') %>%
  gtsummary::add_n(statistic = "{N_miss}", col_label = "**Missing**") %>% 
  gtsummary::modify_column_hide(stat_0)

gtsummary::tbl_merge(list(t1,t2), tab_spanner = FALSE)
```